# How to make jQuery mouse-over effect work in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, hover

Currently I'm working on a rough prototype of a time bar for an online planning tool. People should be able to indicate their availability by hovering over the time bar:

9.00-10.00 | 10.00-11.00 | etc.

When you hover over a certain time block it turns green.

This works fine on a computer, but I'd like to make it work on iPads as well. I read [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) but I'm a beginner when it comes to jQuery, so I don't understand how to implement this in my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
  <td class="c1">9.00 - 10.00</td>
  <td class="c2">10.00 - 11.00</td>
  <td class="c3">etc.</td>
</tr>
</table>


<script>
$( ".c1" ).hover(function() {
    $('.c1').css('background', 'LawnGreen ');
});
$( ".c2" ).hover(function() {
    $('.c2').css('background', 'LawnGreen ');
});
$( ".c3" ).hover(function() {
    $('.c3').css('background', 'LawnGreen ');
});
</script>

<style>
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;}
</style>
```

What code should I add to make this work on iPads as well?

EDIT:

I'm currently testing the solution Kirgan proposed. I tried a very basic implementation to see if I could get the plugin working:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.hammer.js"></script>

<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('test_el');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function(event) {
        alert('hello!');
    });
</script>

<p id="test_el">Tap here</p>

<style>
#test_el {font-size: 100px; border: solid red;}
</style>
```

This code is live on http://test.plantage82.nl

If I open this on an iPhone and tap the 'Tap here' text I should get an alert, right? It doesn't happen, did I make a mistake?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What code should I add?

Comment: mouseover in iOS ? Mouseover doesn't works (it works but look like a bug) in iOS for the simple reason that you don't have mouse on iOS but only your fingers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply - instead of moving over I mean sliding over with your finger. What should I change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of jQuery you are using:

```
$( ".c1" ).bind('hover click', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'LawnGreen ');
});
```

Then again, you can and probably should just use CSS:

```
.c1:hover {
    background: LawnGreen;
}
```

Edit: If that jQuery script does not work, try this:

```
$( ".c1" ).live('hover click', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'LawnGreen ');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. Are you sure your code is correct?

In this case I don't use CSS because I want the background to stay green, also after the mouse pointer is not hovering over anymore. I also want to add a certain value in each td when you hover over, the code snippet above is a simplified version.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Just checking if I made the correct changes: I replaced

     $( ".c1" ).hover(function() {
  $('.c1').css('background', 'LawnGreen ');
 }); with your code snippet. After this change, nothing turns green anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do but it looks strange to have this effect on iOS, maybe look hammer js wich embed mobile action as pinch, drag, touch etc... http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: In the end I would like to have a time bar where people can mark time blocks with different colors. In iOS I want to be able to pick the color I'd like to use (green = available, red = not available etc) and slide over the time blocks I'd like to apply that color to. This data entry should be saved in a database, but I just showed a simplified version of the code to keep it short. Thanks for the link, I will try that solution!

Comment: I tried hammer.js but couldn't get it working. Could you please take a look at my edit and see if I did something wrong? I'm new in this field but definitely willing to learn :) Thnx!